# Show that $\int^{\infty}_0\frac{v}{1+\frac{1}{b}v^{\alpha}}dv=\frac{\pi}{\alpha \sin \left(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}\right)}b^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}$

Tags: calculus

Show that $$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{v}{1+\frac{1}{b}v^{\alpha}}dv=\frac{\pi}{\alpha \sin \left(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}\right)}b^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}$$
This equation shows on the appendix part of a paper I am reading, the author says "after some mathematical manipulation", but I have no clue how to derive this. I tried some online integral calculator, they did not give solutions either.

Any help? THanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know any complex analysis?  Because that I how I would attack it.

Comment: @DougM looks like the result of a beta eulerian integral

Comment: @DougM Yes, I took complex analysis before.

Comment: You'll want to assume $b > 0$ and $\alpha > 2$ to get your integral to converge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set $v=b^{1/\alpha}\tan^{2/\alpha}t$ to rewrite your integral as $$\frac{2b^{2/\alpha}}{\alpha}\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^{4/\alpha-1}tdt=\frac{b^{2/\alpha}}{\alpha}\operatorname{B}(\tfrac{2}{\alpha},\,1-\tfrac{2}{\alpha})=\frac{b^{2/\alpha}}{\alpha}\Gamma(\tfrac{2}{\alpha})\Gamma(1-\tfrac{2}{\alpha})=\frac{\pi b^{2/\alpha}}{\alpha\sin\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}}.$$

Comment: +1 nice answer Jg dont forget the angle of the tan function

Comment: +1 for the nice answer. As Isham commented, this requires $$\left(\pi  a=2 \arg \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)\lor \frac{2 \arg
   \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)}{a}\leq \pi \right)\land \Re(a)>2$$